# Is there any ways I can use environment values in rails? (version6), not Figaro and dotenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I should not use Figaro and dotenv.
I'm now making file named development.sh,

and

```
export USERNAME="user"
export PASSWORD="user"
export HOST="localhost"
echo $USERNAME
echo $PASSWORD
echo $HOST
```

inside is like this.

when I start docker container,
I run

```
sh development.sh
```

but rails app can't understand env values...

this is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("USERNAME") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("PASSWORD") %>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("HOST") %>
```

if my way is wrong, is there any vanilla way to use <%= ENV.fetch("USERNAME") %> env value?
thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _"but rails app can't understand env values"_. Is there an error message? What does it say? Or is there an unexpected result?

Comment: @spickermann Thanks! it says : Keyerror: cannot find database configuration, key not found : USERNAME

Comment: This may be a docker issue because when you run `development.sh` it might not define env variables globally. I think defining env variables in dockerfile will be a better practice and probably solve your issue.